# How to add variable in other class static Dictionary without calling a function?

Tags: c#, static

**Desired outcome:**

Implement a class structure, for testing API without altering the base class.

**Current situation:**

When I write each test for a website, then I'm trying to reuse currently implemented functions to prevent code duplication. Test are called by custom script language (if it can be called like that).

**Problem:**

Since each line of script can only be applied to 1 function, then I can't use polymorthism. Test implementation looks ugly and I want to change that.

**My solution:**

I separated each base testing methods and added a map to each of them to define specific cases.

```
Public static Dictionary <string, dynamic> TestCases
```

This works well, but I always have to add new cases to that dictionary in main class which I don't really like.

**The main question:**

Can I add new cases to this variable without editing main class and calling a function in runtime. Something like:

```
MainTest.TestCases.Add("specific case", ...);
```

But it should be done during compilation.

**Notes:**

Maybe my implementation is not very right so I will accept other suggestions as well.

Comment: Sorry, it's very unclear what you're asking. There are no classes here, so there's no way of knowing which class you don't want to edit. You don't have to edit the class that contains the dictionary to add items to a dictionary. But obviously adding something to a dictionary means writing code somewhere, which means editing a class.

Comment: Sorry, will update it in 24 hours